# is there a way to show Jmeter assertions results in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I um using the performance plugin in Jenkins to launch Jmeter tests. I added some assertions in the jmx file using the GUI ( + assertions listener).
In the Performance Trend I have only the http code and the elapsed time with the different graph.
I would like to show the assertions results in Jenkins.

Is there any way to do that ?

Thank you